# Associate .pl with Perl.exe

Tags: perl, file

I'm having a few problems running perl scripts and the association with Perl. I am unable to run the scripts as follows:

C:\perlscript.pl

I have to run them like this:

C:\perl perlscript.pl

I would like to be able to run them without typing "perl". I believe this is an issue with file assosiation however i have run the following commands and its still doing it:

assoc .pl=PerlScript
ftype PerlScript=C:\bin\perl.exe "%1" %*

I have also checked the ".pl" entry in the default file association list and it points at the Perl.exe

Any ideas guys?

Comment: Its worth noting im running Windows 7 64bit.

Comment: I have installed `ActiveState` in a `Windows Vista` and it works without adding `perl` in cli. Is `perl` part of your path variables?

Comment: Yes it has been set correctly in my path. If i type "perl -v" it list the version etc.

Comment: Are you using `Active State`?I have `Windows Vista 32bit` and for me it works.

Comment: Yes i am using active state